# Facebook Messenger Bot stops working

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a fb messenger bot powered by dialogflow. One day before the bot stops working and am unable to debug the issue.

I am using the Google's Dialogflow for powering the fb bot. 
On Integrations page, Facebook Messenger server is running.

While messaging from fb bot ,I can see the intents are getting detected and fired correctly, but am not getting any response in fb messenger bot.

So Is there any way to debug the issue like log on fb page or something?

Please help

Below is the response from Webhook end.

```
{
    "speech": " Here are what we found for apple  laptops.",
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": 0,
            "platform": "facebook",
            "speech": " Here are what we found for apple  laptops."
        },
        {
            "payload": {
                "facebook": {
                    "attachment": {
                        "payload": {
                            "elements": [
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41aVt1CW-dL._SL160_.jpg",
                                    "subtitle": "Rs. 57,430 on Amazon , Rating : 4.5",
                                    "title": "Apple MacBook Air MQD32HN/A 13.3-inch Laptop",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "web_url",
                                            "url": "https://www.amazon.in/Apple-MacBook-Air-13-3-inch-Integrated/dp/B073Q5R6VR?SubscriptionId=AKIAJZ7ZVEW7WHEFIMWA&tag=pricee360-21&linkCode=sp1&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B073Q5R6VR",
                                            "title": "More Info"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MACBOOKIDA3158352E58B52/1.jpg",
                                    "subtitle": "Rs. 65,999 on Paytm Mall",
                                    "title": "Apple MacBook Air MQD42HN/A (Intel Core i5/ 8GB LPDDR3/ 256GB/ 13.3\"/ Mac OS)",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "web_url",
                                            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-macbook-air-mqd42hn-a-13-inch-laptop-core-i5-8gb-256gb-mac-os-integrated-graphics-silver-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MACBOOIGEN198609B4C8CBF4-pdp?product_id=131486426&discoverability=online&src=grid&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360",
                                            "title": "More Info"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MACBOOKIDA3158352E58B52/1.jpg",
                                    "subtitle": "Rs. 65,999 on Paytm Mall",
                                    "title": "Apple MacBook Air MQD42HN/A (Intel Core i5/ 8GB LPDDR3/ 256GB/ 13.3\"/ Mac OS)",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "web_url",
                                            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-macbook-air-mqd42hn-a-13-inch-laptop-core-i5-8gb-256gb-mac-os-integrated-graphics-silver-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MACBOOIGEN198609B4C8CBF4-pdp?product_id=131486426&discoverability=online&src=grid&svc=2&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360",
                                            "title": "More Info"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MACBOOTELE1525531013F4C5/1.jpg",
                                    "subtitle": "Rs. 65,999 on Paytm Mall",
                                    "title": "Apple MacBook Air MQD42HN/A (Intel Core i5/ 8GB LPDDR3/ 256GB/ 13.3\"/ Mac OS)",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "web_url",
                                            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-macbook-air-mqd42hn-a-13-inch-laptop-core-i5-8gb-256gb-mac-os-integrated-graphics-silver-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MACBOOIGEN198609B4C8CBF4-pdp?product_id=143149022&discoverability=online&src=grid&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360",
                                            "title": "More Info"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "image_url": "https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/product/L/LA/LAPAPPLE-MACBOOROSE73954D5B64792/1.jpg",
                                    "subtitle": "Rs. 89,990 on Paytm Mall",
                                    "title": "Apple Macbook PRO MPXQ2/R2 Core i5 (6th Gen)/8 GB/128 GB/33.78 cm (13.3)/Mac OS)",
                                    "buttons": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "web_url",
                                            "url": "https://paytmmall.com/apple-macbook-pro-mpxq2-r2-core-i5-6th-gen-8-gb-128-gb-33-78-cm-13-3-mac-os-CMPLXLAPAPPLE-MACBOODUMM202563C836CCA-pdp?product_id=145129487&discoverability=online&src=grid&svc=2&utm_source=NDTV&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=NDTV-recharge&utm_term=Gadget360",
                                            "title": "More Info"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "template_type": "generic"
                        },
                        "type": "template"
                    }
                }
            },
            "platform": "facebook",
            "type": 4
        },
        {
            "type": 2,
            "platform": "facebook",
            "title": "Here are some suggestions.",
            "replies": [
                "HP laptops",
                "Lenovo laptops",
                "Dell laptops",
                "Asus laptops"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note : APP is development mode and I have added ids in tester and developer role for testing.

Comment: Dialogflow v1 or v2?

Comment: Right now I am using Dialogflow v1

Comment: Did you try to make a request from Dialogflow Console directly to see if your webhook works on his own? What does "status" field says?

Comment: Working perfectly fine for google assistant,home. Some issue with facebook messenger I think. How can we debug?

Answer (score 0):

Please go into DialogFlow History section and check the "raw interaction log" data from your conversation.

I'm having something similar and for me looks like (checking the raw interaction log) the [fulfillmentMessages node isn't returning the right way.

[image: 1]

Asked for DialogFlow support team about that and waiting their answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the response. Please try out some custom response. I've had such problems many of times. Quick change in response object may give you the result. Dynamic change in response object sometimes behave inaccurately idk maybe because of some escape character.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Go to developers.facebook.com and go to your app. 
Then go to your app and go to Messenger.
On that page you will find 'Show recent errors' under the 'Webhooks' section. This may help you why you're not receiving any messages!